# Build error - Ionic app with Visual Studio

Tags: android, visual-studio, ionic-framework

I try to build my ionic app with Visual Studio 17 but I get the following error:

> "Windows 8 or higher is required to build for Windows"

My OS is Windows 7. I have installed android-sdk, jdk and Apache Ant and I have set the environmental variables.

Is it possible this error means that I have to install a higher version of OS in order to build?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

#### Running Your App

To run or build your app for production, run

```
ionic cordova run android --prod --release
# or
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```